# How to enable append button to GridControl EmbeddedNavigator?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have simple questions how to enable the append button in my GridControl. I have tried lot of things like:

```
GridView.OptionsView.ShowButtonMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ShowButtonModeEnum.ShowAlways;
GridControl.EmbeddedNavigator.OptionsBehavior.AllowAddRows = true;
GridControl.EmbeddedNavigator.Buttons.Append.Enable = true;
GridControl.EmbeddedNavigator.Buttons.Append.Visible = true;
GridControl.EmbeddedNavigator.Enable = true;
GridControl.EmbeddedNavigator.Visible = true;
```

I run out of idea how to solve this simple task. Please help me.

I use DevExpress Version 18.1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to show the Append button only if the grid's DataSource supports the **IBindingList** interface and its **AllowNew** method returns **true**. Otherwise, it's not clear how GridControl should add a new record. 
If your datasource doesn't implement **IBindingList**, consider using the standard **BindingList** class instead.

Alternatively, you can create custom buttons using the [CustomButtons](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.NavigatorButtonsBase.CustomButtons.property) property.